# How to create a Minimax algorithm comparing arrays

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to code a "minimax" algorithm for Tic Tac Toe.

Each node of the tree is of the form `[nil/Int, String]` where the last element is a nine character string describing the board, and the first is an Integer ranking the node, or nil by default.

If the value is nil, it tries to inherit the appropriate value from child nodes.

This is where I get an error, when comparing an array with an array failed.

```
class Scene_TicTacToe #Script 2/2

  def initialize
    #Boardstate as a str from top left corner to bottom right corner.
    @boardstate = "---------"
    #1 = player, -1 = comp
    @active_player = 1
  end

  def wincheck(boardstate=@boardstate)
    #should return -1 for loss, 0 for draw, 1 for win
    ["OOO","XXX"].each do |f|
      for i in 0..2
        if (boardstate[i]+boardstate[i+3]+boardstate[i+6]).chr == f || boardstate[(3*i)..(3*i)+2] == f
          return f == "OOO" ? 1 : -1
        end
      end
      if (boardstate[0]+boardstate[4]+boardstate[8]).chr == f || (boardstate[2]+boardstate[4]+boardstate[6]).chr == f
        return f == "OOO" ? 1 : -1
      end
    end
    return 0
  end

  def computer_play
    #Sets depth,and alpha/beta for pruning, so far so good
    depth = 3
    alpha = -100
    beta = 100
    #@boardstate starts as "---------"
    #@active_player: 1=player, -1=computer
    play(minimax(@boardstate, depth, alpha, beta, @active_player))
  end

  def play(array)
    #Check actual boardside with parameter boardside to see what move has been
    #selected and plays that move
    for i in 0...array[1].length
      if @boardstate[i] != array[1][i]
        #color = array[1][i].chr == "X" ? @ai : @player
        #@cursor.y = (i / 3) * @side
        #@cursor.x = (i % 3) * @side
        #@board.bitmap.fill_rect(@cursor.x,@cursor.y,@side,@side,color)
        @boardstate = array[1].dup
      end
    end
  end

  def minimax(boardstate, depth, alpha, beta, active_player)
    #If bottom node reached, returns [boardstate_score, boardstate]
    #wincheck returns 1 if player wins, -1 if computer wins, and 0 otherwise
    if depth == 0 or wincheck(boardstate) != 0 or (/-/ =~ boardstate) == nil
      return [wincheck(boardstate),boardstate]
    end

    if active_player == 1 #if player's turn
      #Gets an array of all the next possible boardstates and return the one with
      #the best eval.
      child = generate_child(boardstate, active_player)
      child.each do |f| #f = [Int/nil, String]
        if f[0] == nil
          #This should turn all the nil wincheck values to the best value of children nodes
          f[0] = minimax(f[1], depth-1, alpha, beta, -active_player).last[0]
        end
        alpha = [f[0], alpha].max
        if beta <= alpha
          break
        end
      end
      return child.sort_by{|c| c[0]}
    end

    if active_player == -1 #if computer's turn
      #Same as above but with worst eval.
      child = generate_child(boardstate, active_player)
      child.each do |f|
        if f[0] == nil
          f[0] = minimax(f[1], depth-1, alpha, beta, -active_player).first[0]
        end
        beta = [f[0], beta].min
        if beta <= alpha
          break
        end
      end
      #Following line raises "comparison of array with array failed" error :
      return child.sort_by{|c| c[0]}
    end

  end

  def generate_child(boardstate, active_player)
    #returns boardstate string with one X or O more than current boardstate
    #and sets nil as a default wincheck value
    c = active_player == 1 ? "O" : "X"
    a = []
    for i in 0...boardstate.length
      if boardstate[i].chr == "-"
        s = boardstate.dup
        s[i]= c
        a << [nil, s]
      end
    end
    return a
  end

end
```

Error: comparison of array with array failed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'd really like to run your code, but alas I get `undefined method 'wincheck' for #<Scene_TicTacToe:0x008a9ab0>`. Would you be able to provide the `wincheck` method and any other missing code so we can have a go at debugging it?

Comment: Thanks ! I edited the method in. As for the rest, it deals with displaying everything on screen and it is specific code/methods provided by RPG Maker XP (the software I'm using for this) so I'm afraid it won't be of any help... Incidentally, I #'ed some lines that would not work either (such as .fill_rect)